# For Vaadin Combo Box I need to display one value and set another value

Tags: vaadin

I have Vaadin Combo Box with below items

```
Application
Federation
Innovation
```

When the user selects Application from the dropdown box I need to set APP in the similar way

```
Federation - FED
Innovation - INV
```

So when I fetch the need only short code of it not the entire name. How to achieve that?.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This basic case you can do like this:

```
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
cb.addItem("FED");
cb.setItemCaption("FED", "Federation");
cb.addItem("INV");
cb.setItemCaption("INV", "Innovation");
main.addComponent(cb);

// to show the value:
cb.setImmediate(true); // update the label immediatly
Label selected = new Label(cb);
main.addComponent(selected);
```

But I really recommend you get to know Items and Properties in Vaadin. Each selection in the ComboBox (and many other components in Vaadin) is an Item that can have any number of properties. You could show any of those properties as item caption in the ComboBox.

See [the book](http://vaadin.com/book) for more info.